# Getting Values From Form And Using It In JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am having difficulty in simple program...

I have a simple html form from which i get 3 values as integers and then they are submitted to a JavaScript function using this line
This is the function that i am using

```
<script language="javascript">
function Secured_Rescaled_Marks(form)
{
    var address = form.total_marks.value;
    window.alert(address);  
    //var secured = (rescale_marks/total_marks)*secured_marks;
    //alert('secured');
}
</script>
```

and this is the form

```
<form>
<table cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#6699CC">
<b>Total Marks:</b>
<input name="text" name="total_marks" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</br>
<table cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#6699CC">
<b>Secured Marks:</b>
<input name="text" name="secured_marks">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</br>
<table cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#6699CC">
<b> Rescale Marks:</b>
<input name="textarea" name="rescale_marks">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</br>
    <input type="button" onsubmit="return Secured_Rescaled_Marks(this);" name="order" value="Secured_Rescaled_Marks??"/>

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I need to calculate such formula on form submission and alert the result....

```
var secured = (rescale_marks/total_marks)*secured_marks;
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You're not showing us your function or all pertinent HTML, so it's a little tough to find your issue.  Show us what you're trying!

Comment: And show us THAT you are trying: make an effort to understand the question guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should give your form a `name`, then you can use one of these common methods:

```
document.FormName.elements["element_name"].value;//select by name
//or
document.FormName.elements[index].value;//select by index position
```

**Note:** `FormName` is the form name in the example

[source](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml) and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3uLt/1/)

And then to use this value in your function, you need to transform it from string to number like this:

```
var val = document.FormName.elements["element_name"].value;
val = parseFloat(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` tags have two names, i.e.:

```
<input name="text" name="total_marks" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="total_marks" id="total_marks"/>
```

I added an ID for you, because with an ID, you can get your values using `document.getElementById('total_marks');`

And when you do your math after retrieving your values, you should make sure they're numbers (in your case, integers), i.e.:

```
var tmarks = parseInt(document.getElementById('total_marks'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors on your form (fixed)

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return Secured_Rescaled_Marks(this);">
<table cellpadding="3">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#6699CC">
       <b>Total Marks:</b>
       <input type="text" name="total_marks" />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</br>
<table cellpadding="3">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#6699CC">
       <b>Secured Marks:</b>
       <input type="text" name="secured_marks">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </br>
 <table cellpadding="3">
  <tbody>
   <tr> 
    <td bgcolor="#6699CC">
     <b> Rescale Marks:</b>
      <input type="text" name="rescale_marks">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </br>
 <input type="submit" name="order" value="Secured_Rescaled_Marks??"/>
 <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>​
```

**JS**
`<script language="javascript">` should be `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
function Secured_Rescaled_Marks(frm)
{
    var rescale_marks=parseFloat(frm.rescale_marks.value);
    var total_marks=parseFloat(frm.total_marks.value);
    var secured_marks=parseFloat(frm.secured_marks.value);
    var secured = (rescale_marks/total_marks)*secured_marks;
    if(isNaN(secured)) return false;
    if(confirm(secured)) 
    {
        this.submit();
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6beaM/5/)

Comment: Things your are missing: the script tag is bogus (language attribute, wHAT?)

Comment: The computation needs to be done in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: The form is passed as a parameter to the event handler.